# OAF remove all rows from view object VO

Tags: oaf

I can not find a method to make the VO empty.

In collections it's rather straight-forward

```
arrayList.clear();
```

But there's no similar method in VO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no normal method names because VO can have many row sets. For example, you can put query results with different parameters in different row sets and then work with both of them. VO is actually a list of lists, so all VO methods are named differently.

One-liner solution

```
vo.executeEmptyRowSet();
```

If you need to handle each row individually

```
vo.reset();
while (vo.hasNext()) {
    oracle.jbo.Row row = vo.next()
    handleRow(row);
    row.remove();
}
```